How to find top n correlated items when an input is passed and their values in pandas dataframe
I am new to pandas and trying to get top n correlated items when an index is provided.
For example in the following image how do I get all the correlated items for duration
Correlation Matrix
I generated correlation matrix on my dataframe and reshaped the matrix with the following code
def get_top_abs_correlations(df, n=50):
     au_corr = df.corr().abs().unstack()
     input = "duration"
     for index, value in au_corr.items():
         if input in index:
            print(index, value)

I'm trying to figure out - how to filter out the duplicate correlation pairs and retrieve top n correlated items for only "duration"

Welcome to SO! Please no pictures for data, code, errors... see why in [ask]. Post datafames by copy-pasting the output of e.g. print(df)

Here's how you can modify your get_top_abs_correlations function to filter out the duplicate correlation pairs and retrieve only the top n correlated items for some input feature:
def get_top_abs_correlations(df, input_feature, n=50):
    # Calculate absolute correlations
    au_corr= df.corr().abs().unstack()

    # Filter out duplicate correlation pairs
    corr_pairs = au_corr[au_corr.index.get_level_values(0) != au_corr.index.get_level_values(1)]

    # Get top n correlated items for input_feature
    top_correlations = corr_pairs[input_feature].nlargest(n)

    return top_correlations    

This function will return the top n correlated items for the given input_feature in terms of absolute correlation values. It filters out duplicate correlation pairs and retrieves the top n correlated items.

Please do not post AI generated answers, this is forbidden
